# JConsole of JBoss EAP 7.1.1.0.10 has differences between two installation

Tags: linux, jboss, rhel, jconsole

for work I installed the same version of JBoss EAP (7.1.1.0.10 version) on two Linux servers with the same version of RHEL.

As per title if I run jconsole on a server and click on MBeans tab, I see the jboss.as, jboss.as.expr and jboss.jsr77 modules on the left menu, as you can see from the following screenshot:

[image: jconsole-mbeans tab first server]

Well, on the second server these three modules cannot be seen:

[image]

I followed the same installation on both servers, same RHEL, same JBoss version .... what could it depend on this difference?
Maybe should I repeat the installation on the server which has not that entries?